# Sorting an array from smallest to largest (Not a bubble sort)

Tags: arrays, sorting

I need to look through an `array(ar[])`, find the smallest value(smallest), transfer it to `index[0]` at `ar2[]`, and replace the number at `ar[]` with 1000 so I can loop through and consecutively put the other lowest numbers in `ar2[]`.

```js
public class Sort
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {

        int ar[] = {6,7,2,1,5,9,4,2,3};
        int i, j;
        int ar2[] = new int[9];
        final int ONE = 1000;

        for(i=0; i < ar.length; i++)
        { 
            int smallest = ar[0];

            for(j=1; j<ar2.length; j++)
            {
                if (ar[i]<ar[j])
                {
                    smallest = ar[i];
                    ar[i] = ONE
                }

                ar2[j] = smallest;
            }
        }

        for(j=0;j<ar2.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.println("ar2[" + j + "] = " + ar[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  If you make an effort to format your code properly, you are more likely to get helpful answers.

Comment: You should also explain to us what is the problem with your code, what is the current output, what is it suppose to output, and what have you tried to fix it so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix for your sorting code: **But this is not good algorithm enough**. It has O(n^2) complexity, but other ones has O(N*log2N). Take a look  [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) to learn more.

```
for (i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    int smallest = ar[i];
    int smallestIndex = i;
    for (j = 0; j < ar2.length; j++) {
        if (ar[j] < smallest) {
            smallest = ar[j];
            smallestIndex = j;
        }
    }
    ar2[i] = smallest;
    ar[smallestIndex] = ONE;
}
```